# while loop (Python)

Tags: python, while-loop

If I wanted to say something for a while loop such as: `while time is greater than or equal to 0`, would it simply be written as `while time > or == 0`? Or is there no way to do this?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: The relation "is greater than or equal to" is treated as a single statement, not an alternation of two disjoint  ones. The presence of the word "or" in the English reading doesn't imply that the operator `or` is involved in the translation to Python.  
In mathematics, this "greater than or equal" relationship is written with the symbol ≥, but usually in programming languages, and certainly in Python, it's written `>=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `while time >= 0` (equivalent to `while time > 0 or time == 0`)

```
>>> 0 >= 0
True
>>> 1 >= 0
True
>>> -1 >= 0
False
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
while time >= 0:
    pass
    #here be dragons
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting in Python example:

```
time = 0 
while time < 100: 
    time = time + 1 
    print time
```